# Wordpress, how to make search for posts using get method?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I am building a WordPress theme for myself to meet my needs, so what I am looking for now is make a search using a get method in php.

If my url is something like this :

```
http://www.MyWordPressWebsite.com/search.php?string=Bananas+and+apples
```

In my search.php I would like to do something like this:

```
string = $_GET["string"];

 $fruits_args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'fruits',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'cat'           =>  'fruits'
); 
 $fruits = new WP_Query($fruits_args);
```

So how do I making the loop related to the string that I get from the the get method ?

comparing the search string the the post type, category and post title would be enough.

Comment: Can you please [check this out](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter)

Comment: God, this is so easy ! Do you know how exactly this works ? I mean what fields are compared to the string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use query_posts() instead and Wordpress will handle the search with those parameters. You can add as many parameters as you want.

Example:

```
<?php $my_post_type = (get_query_var('my_post_type')) ? get_query_var('my_post_type') : false;?>
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => $my_post_type));?>

<?php //Normal loop here ?>
```

For more info visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

I hope this help